Assets aren't loading when I add a custom domain for gh-pages
I'm using React native expo. it works fine on github pages after deployment WITHOUT a custom domain. but once I add a custom domain and access it, it appears that all the assets are gone (fonts and images). The console prints 404 errors for the assets.
All the configurations for my expo app are the default ones, the only changes I made are for the web deployment process which are provided by the official expo docs (https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/publishing-websites/#github-pages)
